# How do I serialize $_POST data in ajax from a php redirect

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am having users fill in a form on page A, I then redirect to page B sending $_POST data with it. I've seen that I can serialize post data from a form like this `$("form").serialize()` or `this.serialize()` but I don't want to retrieve data from a form I need to get it from $_POST. How do I go about serializing $_POST data not from a form that exists on the current page?

Comment: please edit this question and ask more clearly, this is confusing

Comment: Why are you doing that? Maybe you could send the information with AJAX and after receving the response, make the other one with that information? But I still don't understand the use of it.

Comment: How are you posting the data? Ajax? Otherwise I'm not sure how you can serialize the data with JS and "redirect" (I assume you're posting) it to another page using the POST method? Show us your code.

Comment: Its a search. They can choose to search by different criteria. When they submit I redirect to a page that uses datatables.

Comment: Instead of filling form A and redirecting with data to B, why not simply post from A to B?

Comment: `$_POST` is PHP and `serialize()` is JavaScript. Those two don't typically run at the same time. Can you provide some more detail on the mechanics of this?

Comment: Lots to learn, but AJAX looks like it will be what you want to do some research on

Comment: I am doing ajax on page 2, using data from a form on page 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this in case anyone else ever wonders how to do this.
`var post_info = [];` creates an array to hold all of the $_POST variables. 
This is what takes all the post variables and puts them into a json array for ajax `post_info = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;`. And the ajax looks like normal.

```
            "ajax": {
                "url": "ajax/test.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {post_info: post_info}
            },
```

On the php side I didn't need to json_decode because ajax sends this as a $_POST variable. Except it is now a multidimensional array so accessing variables looks like this `$_POST['post']['item']`. And there you go. I've never answered my own question before.

Answer (score 0):

When someone submits a form, unless you use Javascript to override the default browser behaviour, they will be taken to page B. You define the "method" and "action" of the form to get the behaviour you want. So, to POST data you'd use method="POST" and to go to pageb.php you'd set action="/pageb.php". Then in pageb.php you can access the POST variables from the form on pagea. E.g.

pagea:

```
<form name="aform" action="/pageb.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Type your name in, hit submit, get redirected to pageb.php. Then on pageb:

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST["name"]; 
    echo $name;
?>
```

You see the name. Not very exciting though.

You could alternatively use Ajax and the jQuery serialize function to send the form data to pageb.php without leaving pagea.

You could do something like this:

```
<form id="aform" action="/pageb.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm(event)">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitForm() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('/pageb.php', $("#aform").serialize(), function(response) {
             // Do something with the response
        });
    };

</script>
```

That's pretty basic but it stops the form behaving normally, serializes the form and sends it to pageb. pageb.php would have to output text of some kind, plain or JSON perhaps depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is what i am doing. When I hit pageb.php I am doing an a ajax call to query the datatabse and populate datatables. On pageb.php the form is gone but I have the $_POST data. The problem with this whole situation is datatables. I cannot load a page without populating datatable or datatables will forever says "loading" and not render anything else on the page.

Comment: I think you've added an extra step. Start pageb with PHP to perform your database queries, then either redirect to another page or render pageb as HTML. There's no need to send of an Ajax call after you've changed page